# [Error 10025]: Line 5:3 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'dotProductSum'

Tags: group-by, hive, recommendation-engine

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS recommendations;
CREATE TABLE recommendations AS
SELECT
  movie_id AS movie_id,
  movie_id_2 AS movie_id_2,
  (N * dotProductSum - ratingSum * rating2Sum) / (SQRT(N * ratingSqSum - ratingSum * ratingSum) * SQRT(N * rating2SqSum - rating2Sum * rating2Sum))
   AS correlation
FROM
  coratings
GROUP BY
  coratings.movie_id, coratings.movie_id_2, coratings.dotProductSum
ORDER BY
  movie_id;
```

i have added dotProductSum into query still i get below error.

org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 5:3 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'dotProductSum'

below one is the coratings table

```
CREATE TABLE coratings AS
SELECT
  a.movie_id ,
  b.movie_id AS movie_id_2 ,
  COUNT(*) AS N ,
  SUM(a.rating) AS ratingSum ,
  SUM(b.rating) AS rating2Sum ,
  SUM(a.rating * b.rating) AS dotProductSum ,
  SUM(a.rating * a.rating) AS ratingSqSum ,
  SUM(b.rating * b.rating) AS rating2SqSum  
FROM
  movies_ratings a
  JOIN movies_ratings b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE
  a.movie_id < b.movie_id
GROUP BY
 a.movie_id, b.movie_id
HAVING
  N >= 30;
```

movies_ratings table

```
USE rec_engine;

-- table definition will be created
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS movies_ratings ;

-- here 
CREATE TABLE movies_ratings ( user_id INT, movie_id INT, rating INT, `time_stamp` INT )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    "field.delim"=",",
    "skip.header.line.count"="1"
);

-- data in local file system /home/hive folder. otherwise can't load.
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'ratings_small.csv'
OVERWRITE INTO TABLE movies_ratings;
```

Comment: try to wrap `(N * dotProductSum - ratingSum * rating2Sum) / (SQRT(N * ratingSqSum - ratingSum * ratingSum) * SQRT(N * rating2SqSum - rating2Sum * rating2Sum))` within an aggregation such as `COUNT(...),AVG(...),SUM(...)...`, and remove `, coratings.dotProductSum` from `GROUP BY list`.

Comment: wrapping and adding SUM solved my problem. But isn't it affect the correlation final result. and why is it happen